# Hibernate Reset (Start PK from 0) using Code

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, primary-key

I have a table that fills every day by some batch process.

I delete all the records and add new records through program using hibernate.

But in this case my ID (Auto increment PK) +1 every time.

I understand that delete query will just remove row and will not affect table information (like increment counter).

I also know that there are only 3 ways to do this.

1. Alter table with AUTO_INCREMENT set back to 1.
2. Truncate table
3. Drop and Create table again.

None of above will be useful in my case as I don't want to do anything manually.

1st one need fire a DDL query which I think not possible through hibernate.
2nd Same as above + Once we restart tomcat - hibernate.cfg.xml will execute and above issue can be resolve. So this is also not possible.
3rd Same as above (2nd point).

So some one please advice for any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

> 1st one need fire a DDL query which I think not possible through
>   hibernate.

Why does this have to be done via Hibernate? Just get hold of your datasource and execute your DDL. Assuming that the datasource Hibernate is using has appropriate permissions. Otherwise define a second datasource which permits the use of ALTER TABLE.